# Strict henselianization of complete intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, etale-cohomology

As far as I understand (and tbh for my purposes), one of the main points of strict henselisation of a local ring is that it computes the stalk at a point of a scheme in the étale topology. In the smooth case using étale coordinates, these are rather easy to understand. However, I don't think I know how to do any sort of computation for any sort of singularity. My hope would be that the strict henselisation of complete intersections have a nice description, but I'd be interested in any class where we have a good description of them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly.   If a local ring $R$ is a quotient of a regular local ring $R = S/I$, then $S^{\mathrm{sh}}/IS^{\mathrm{sh}}$ is a strict Henselization of $R$, that is its isomorphic to  $R^{\mathrm{sh}}$.  See for instance https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05WS  Are you assuming that your scheme is not locally embeddable, so being a complete intersection means that, after completion, it is a complete intersection in a regular local ring?

Comment: @KarlSchwede my apologies, I was not aware of that. I think my question was just the hope that "things become easier at the stalk", but that doesn't seem to be the case.